# How to write the procedures SQL for the Table report

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 table:

[image]

I want to write Procedure so that when changing Table Job the table Report will change accordingly

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Show us your current code attempt.

Comment: What should change, what is the relation between job and report. Without mentioning all these details you will not get proper response.

Comment: What tool are you looking to use? The end result would be easier in your presentation layer, rather than in SQL, due to the need to pivot the data.

Comment: Also, storing data as a delimited list in a table is a bad idea. Especially as this means you've changed your `int` value to a `varchar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) if you use SQL-Server 2016 or above

> If you dont have SQL-Server 2016, then google for a string_split function - There are plenty of them on this site, and use that instead for string_split

This here is a way to do it with dynamic SQL pivot

**UPDATE2 Make TableReport to change when values change**

This checks if TableReport Exists and if it does, then it should be dropped. I then just added an SELECT INTO statement into the dynamic SQL which recreates the table.

```
DECLARE @Str NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Str2 NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @Str = STUFF(
                   (
                       SELECT DISTINCT
                              ','+QUOTENAME(Namejob)
                       FROM tablejob FOR XML PATH('')
                   ), 1, 1, '');
-- PRINT @Str
SET @str2 = N'select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by idemp) as ID,Name2 as Name, '+@Str+' into dbo.TableReport from (
select b.idemp,Names as Name2,Names,namejob from tablecustomer a cross apply dbo.[fn_split_string_using_multiple_delimiters](idjob,'','')
left join tableemp b on a.idemp =b.idemp
left join tablejob c on stringlist = c.idjob 
) z




PIVOT 
(count(names) for Namejob in ('+@Str+'
)
) as x';

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableReport', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.TableReport; 
--PRINT @Str2;
EXEC (@Str2);
```

**UPDATE for NON SQL-Server2016 Version**

> First you must create a function to split your string

**String splitter function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.[fn_split_string_using_multiple_delimiters]
(
      @String    VARCHAR(MAX),  -- input string
      @delimiter VARCHAR(32)    -- delimiter list 
)
RETURNS @Table TABLE(rowid INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,        
stringlist VARCHAR(MAX)
)
BEGIN

        DECLARE @Xml AS XML
        DECLARE @derived_string VARCHAR(MAX)

        ;WITH N1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
        N2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS X, N1 AS Y),
        N3 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS X, N2 AS Y),
        N4 (n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY X.n)
        FROM N3 AS X, N3 AS Y)

        SELECT @derived_string=STUFF((SELECT '' + (Case When
                PATINDEX('%[' + @delimiter + ']%',SUBSTRING(@String,Nums.n,1)) >0
                Then ',' else LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@String,Nums.n,1))) end)
        FROM N4 Nums WHERE Nums.n<=LEN(@String)  FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'')

        SET @Xml = cast(('<a>'+replace(@derived_string,
                ',','</a><a>')+'</a>') AS XML)

        INSERT INTO @Table SELECT A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
                as [Column] FROM @Xml.nodes('a') AS FN(a)

RETURN
END
GO
```

> This hardcoded SQL is just the same way as with 2016 string_split - It will also be the same in dynamic way.

**Harcoded SQL with function**

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by idemp) as ID,Name2 as Name, [A],[B],[C] from (
select b.idemp,Names as Name2,Names,namejob from tablecustomer a cross apply dbo.[fn_split_string_using_multiple_delimiters](idjob,',')
left join tableemp b on a.idemp =b.idemp
left join tablejob c on stringlist = c.idjob 
)x

PIVOT 
(count(names) for Namejob in ([A],[B],[C]
)
) as x
```

**Test Data**

```
   create  table dbo.tablejob  (idjob int, namejob varchar(50))
insert into tablejob
values
(1,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(3,'c')

create table dbo.tablecustomer (serialno int,idcustomer varchar(50),idemp varchar(50),idjob varchar(50))
insert into tablecustomer

values
(1,'0001','00001','1,3'),
(2,'0002','00002','1'),
(3,'0003','00001','2,3')

create table dbo.tableemp (idemp varchar(50),Names varchar(50))
insert into tableemp

values
('00001','Jon'),
('00002','Az')
```

**Dynamic SQL**

```
DECLARE @Str NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Str2 NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @Str = STUFF(
                   (
                       SELECT DISTINCT
                              ','+QUOTENAME(Namejob)
                       FROM tablejob FOR XML PATH('')
                   ), 1, 1, '');
-- PRINT @Str
SET @str2 = N'select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by idemp) as ID,Name2 as Name, '+@Str+' from (
select b.idemp,Names as Name2,Names,namejob from tablecustomer a cross apply string_split(idjob,'','')
left join tableemp b on a.idemp =b.idemp
left join tablejob c on value = c.idjob 
) z




PIVOT 
(count(names) for Namejob in ('+@Str+'
)
) as x';

--PRINT @Str2;
EXEC (@Str2);
```

**Hardcoded SQL**

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by idemp) as ID,Name2 as Name, [A],[B],[C] from (
select b.idemp,Names as Name2,Names,namejob from tablecustomer a cross apply string_split(idjob,',')
left join tableemp b on a.idemp =b.idemp
left join tablejob c on value = c.idjob 
)x




PIVOT 
(count(names) for Namejob in ([A],[B],[C]
)
) as x
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: I'm sory I have SQL 2014 Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'.

Comment: Thanks you! I want to when changing Table Job then table Report auto change